# Java replaceAll multiple chars with reference

Tags: java, string, replace, char

Good evening!

I have to add a backslash (`\`) before different characters.
This work but is not the good way:

```
test = test.replaceAll("\\(", "\\\\(");
test = test.replaceAll("\\&", "\\\\&");
```

... and so on.
The following code is much better but my problem is to search multiple chars in the string. (B E) or (B,E) doesn't work.

```
String test = "ABCDEFG";
test = test.replaceAll("(B)","\\$1");
System.out.println(test);
```

Is there a way to search multiple chars and add a backslash in front of with only one replaceAll call?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `test = test.replaceAll("([B,E])","\\\\$1");`

Comment: Just be aware of fact that `[B,E]` means you will escape not only B or E but also `,` comma. JBNizet most likely forgot to remove it after copying it from your question. You can find more info about `[...]` at http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html